# How to make a function which returns a value after a variable is set by an EventListener?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, dom-events

I have an `EventListener` and a function `generator.gettext`.
Code:

```
var generator = {
    gettext: function (mytext) {
        //I send a message which is intercepted by my content script. 
        //Later my content script will send a reply back which will be processed by 'receiver'
        window.postMessage({
            type: "MESSAGE",
            text: mytext
        }, "*");
        while (generatedtext == "") {
            //WAIT until generatedtext is set by 'receiver'
        }
        return generator.generatedtext;
    },

    generatedtext: ""
};

function receiver(event) {
    if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_CONTENTSCRIPT")) {
        generator.generatedtext = event.data.text;
    }
}
window.addEventListener('message', receiver, false);
```

I want that `generator.gettext` returns `generator.generatedtext` but I can't make it wait until `receiver` sets it. I have the impression that the `EventListener` is locked while `generator.gettext` is called. I have to change it so it becomes asynchronous and uses a callback parameter, but I'm new into this and don't know how to make it work. Can somebody help me?

**EDIT:** What I want to do is to process input on a website. There is a Javascript file and I want that input is processed by my content script. I redirected the javascript-file to a modified one on my hard drive. I change a line where the javascript loads the input. When I submit text the Javascript file calls something like `var message = generator.gettext(mytext.value);` My code above is injected into the page and has to send mytext to my content-script and has to return the output of my content-script.

Comment: I think I have a vague idea of what you want, but it will help if you refine the core idea a bit. For instance generator.getText() isn't actually being called anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're asking, though it isn't very clear.

You are posting a message and you want to store the result on generator.generatedtext. You are already doing so.

```
var generator = {
    generatedtext:'',
    gettext: function (mytext) {
        window.postMessage({
            type: "MESSAGE",
            text: mytext
        }, "*");
    }
};

window.addEventListener('message', function(ev){
    if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_CONTENTSCRIPT")) {
        generator.generatedtext = event.data.text;
    }
},false);
```

Unless there is some other usage that you are trying to do but haven't made clear, this is all you need. There is no need to have generator.gettext() return anything, since the message event listener is assigning the messages being received to generator.generatedtext.

If this isn't exactly what you wanted, post a comment with more details and I'll try to help you out.

Comment: Hi thanks, it's important that I can call a function which returns generatedtext. I edited my question to make clear what I want to do. I hope you can help me.

Comment: That unfortunately isn't any clearer. I'm available on gchat, geuis.teses@gmail.com